# Memory Overflow with React PDF / renderer, unable to render high amounts of data

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make an app with dynamic pdf generation, that takes a specific subset of data and renders it thru react-pdf/renderer. As it follows, I actually do have a working method that will go through each dataset, find out what kind of styling they have, and then make them into an object storing the data, styles, and what kind of attribute it is. The problem I am facing here is that when the array / dataset gets to around a length of 45, the app will crash with a memory overflow.

> Uncaught (in promise) abort("Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with  -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X  with X higher than the current value 134217728, (2) compile with  -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1  which allows increasing the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY to a higher value before the program runs, or (4) if you want malloc to return NULL (0) instead of this abort, compile with  -s ABORTING_MALLOC=0 ") at Error

I have narrowed down this issue being in my .map method in the render:

```
  finished_data.map(singleUnit => {
    switch(true){
      case singleUnit.title: return <Text style={styles.tags}>{singleUnit.data} {"\n\n"}</Text>;
      case singleUnit.bold: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor, fontFamily: 'Crimson Bold',}}>{singleUnit.data}</Text>;
      case singleUnit.underline: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor, fontFamily: 'Crimson Regular', textDecoration: 'underline'}}>{singleUnit.data}</Text>
      case singleUnit.italics: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor, fontFamily:'Crimson Italic',}}>{singleUnit.data}</Text>;
      case singleUnit.normal: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor, fontFamily: 'Crimson Regular',}}>{singleUnit.data} </Text>;
      case singleUnit.span: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor,fontFamily: 'Crimson Regular'}}>{singleUnit.data}</Text>;
      case singleUnit.color: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor, fontFamily: 'Crimson Regular'}}>{singleUnit.data}</Text>;
      case singleUnit.underline_bold: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor, fontFamily:'Crimson Bold', textDecoration: 'underline'}}>{singleUnit.data}</Text>;
      case singleUnit.italic_bold: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor, fontFamily:'Crimson Italic Bold',}}>{singleUnit.data}</Text>;
      case singleUnit.italic_underline: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor, fontFamily:'Crimson Italic', textDecoration: 'underline'}}>{singleUnit.data}</Text>;
      case singleUnit.all3: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor,fontFamily: 'Crimson Italic Bold', textDecoration: 'underline'}}> {singleUnit.data} </Text>;
      case singleUnit.notes: return <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Crimson Regular',}}>{'\n\n'}{singleUnit.data}</Text>;
      case singleUnit.anchor: return <Text style={{color: singleUnit.styleData.color, backgroundColor: singleUnit.styleData.bgcolor, textDecoration: 'underline', fontFamily: 'Crimson Regular'}}> {singleUnit.data} </Text>;
      case singleUnit.finished: return <Text>{"\n\n"}</Text>;
```

The inline styling is due to the fonts not working correctly. But the issue persists inside of case singleUnit.normal, because that is the highest counting one at any certain point. Taking that part out, it will generate fine, but as long as the array count stays under around 45.

I understand that this is a currently known issue, but for a much earlier revision. There were no relevant fixes that I could find with this, and trying any issue i've seen has been unsuccessful. Is there something else I am missing here?